# Running a nodejs app on a docker container gives " Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/nodemon' "

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

Here is my Dockerfile which is at the root of the nodejs application.

```
# Build from  LTS version of node (version 12)
FROM node:12

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Define app diretory inside image
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# package.json AND package-lock.json are copied where available 
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/

# install modules
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /usr/src/app

# Bind app to port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run app
CMD [ "nodemon", "./bin/www" ]
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: 'mongo:3.4.1'
    ports:
      - "27017:27017" 
  backend-app:
    container_name: school-backend
    restart: always
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
  frontend-app:
    container_name: angular-frontend
    restart: always
    build: ./angular-app
    ports:
      - "4200:4200"
```

I execute the command `docker-compose up`

Then I get this error

```
school-backend  | Error: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/nodemon'
school-backend  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:966:15)
school-backend  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:842:27)
school-backend  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
school-backend  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
school-backend  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
school-backend  |   requireStack: []
school-backend  | }
```

In the Dockerfile, I copy the `package.json` to the working directory `/usr/src/app\`.

Then I  do `npm install` which would install nodemon since it is declared in the `package.json`

But, why is the module given as absent?

Comment: The Node source will never change once you've built the image; if you update the image you need to delete and recreate the container.  So running `nodemon` doesn't add anything here and you could just run plain `node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not globally installed then.

In this case, you have to call the nodemon bin inside the node_modules:  `./node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `npx` like this `CMD [ "npx", "nodemon", "./bin/www" ]`.

npx will run programs from the `node_modules/.bin` directory.

Comment: `npx` command did not work inside the docker container.